# Different cases for nested master pages

Tags: asp.net, nested, master-pages

In my website I have pages with several layouts:
a page with a header, a page with no header, a page with two columns, a page with 3 columns etc. There are of course pages with a combination of these tarits: a page with header and two columns, page with header and three columns, no header and 2 columns, and on and on ...

So my question is: what is the best way to build master pages for these layouts, should I use nested master pages, and if so how ? or should I create multiple master pages covering all scenarios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would use a Main Master Page to import the required universally CSS and JS files and then generate the Nested Master Pages from it. It looks like more atomic to me. And you also prevent the code repetition.

Comment: So, what youre saying is create a nested master page for each and every case ?

Comment: Exactly. Using different master pages for all kind of page reduce the reusability. You can control pages step by step by using nested master pages.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big the site is, I'd use separate master pages instead of nested ones which is a really sloppy solution not to mention the fact that it complicates programmatic access...

Comment: the number of different master pages in this case can get to above 20, isn't there another solution ?

Comment: Only common artifacts go in master pages to begin; specific page components are part of the page itself. Create your headers, etc. as controls and use a single master page. Remember, at the end of the day a master page is a user control itself.